# how to stop getting exponents on barchart graph and extending number on y axis

Tags: r

I keep getting exponents on the y axis and on top of the bar. How do I change it so it stops showing up as exponents. I am also trying to get the y axis to go up to 8 million.

```
obama <- data.frame(date=c("March 27", "March 31"),
                    enrollment=c(6000000, 7066000))


ggplot(data = obama, aes(x= date, y=enrollment))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ggtitle("Obamacare Enrollment")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_text(aes(label=enrollment), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5
```

[image: my obamacare enrollment graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the labelling have a look at the `scales` package which provides e.g. convenience functions `label_number` and `number`. The limits of an axis can be set via e.g. the `limits` argument of the scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)

obama <- data.frame(date=c("March 27", "March 31"),
                    enrollment=c(6000000, 7066000))


ggplot(data = obama, aes(x= date, y=enrollment))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(), limits = c(NA, 8e6)) +
  ggtitle("Obamacare Enrollment")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::number(enrollment)), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using `ggplot` another option is to suppress scientific notation before plotting using:

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

[image: Plot without scientific notation]

Answer (score 0):

Try `barplot` with base R and set `option(scipen = 999)`

```
options(scipen=999)
p <- barplot(enrollment~date,obama)
with(obama,text(p, enrollment/2, labels = enrollment))
```

[image]